# Error: "Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection" - Docker

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I know that this question has been asked multiple times in the past but I am litterly stuck with this docker situation.

```
PS C:\docker> docker-compose up
Pulling postgresdb (docker.io/bitnami/postgresql:13.3.0)...
ERROR: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: net/http: request canceled (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
```

I am using simple home network without any proxies, while earlier docker was working fine and it has been hit recently.

Using: Below Envrionment

OS: Windows 11
RAM: 16GB
Docker Desktop: v20.10.5

My DockerConfig

```
{
  "registry-mirrors": [],
  "insecure-registries": [],
  "debug": false,
  "experimental": false,
  "features": {
    "buildkit": true
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue could be due to [docker hub rate limiting](https://www.docker.com/increase-rate-limits). You can subscribe for more bandwidth, or setup your own private registry. You can try out other public registry like [this](https://gallery.ecr.aws/).

Comment: You get HTTP 403 errors from the Docker rate limiting, not network connectivity issues.

Comment: Nope, you should get 429 with a message saying something like "...reached pull rate limit". However, you will also see symptoms  like timeout or cancelled half-way. The answer has clearly stated **"could be"**.